# Is this possible to convert a million digit number to 1000 digit number by a certain mathematical operation in C++ or C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I am working on project and ran into an issue.
Now I want to know is there anyway to reduce digits of a big number?  For example convert a million digit number to 1000 digit number.

Comment: Use an arbitrary precision library that has floating point numbers (maybe `mpf`?); then you can make a number with exponent value of one million and a mantissa of any desired precision.

Comment: You don't happen to work for the bank where I have my mortgage, do you? :p

Comment: If this is a serious question, you should give some more details, else I'm sure tham more, err.. 'unhelpful' comments will follow.  If you're trolling, please fish elsewhere.

Comment: You can take the (base 10) log of the number. That reduces it from 10 million digits down to 6 digits to the left of the decimal place, plus however many digits to the right you need for precision.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but in C++ it takes too time. :(

Comment: In future, please try to keep questions like this language-specific.  The way you would do this in C# is completely different than in C++.  Plus, you'll avoid attracting the ire of the C++ crowd, who are a bunch of ... users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a redundancy in the object you are trying to describe or you can deal with slight data loss, there are a lot of ways for dimensional reduction:

- PCA
- Wavelets
- b-adic representation of your numbers for an appropriate b
- other compression algorithms (lossy or lossless)